# NSMutableDictionary won't append

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>Dictionaries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>One</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Data</key>
            <data>
            qqqqqg==
            </data>
        </dict>
        <key>Two</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Data</key>
            <data>
            qqqqqg==
            </data>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Which is essentially an `[NSMutableDictionary]` that has other children dictionaries, all using the same number of objects and keys. The problem is that when I try and add another dictionary in the the existing 'Dictionaries' it wipes out all the others. I've tried using several functions including,  `setObject: forKey:`, `setDictionary: forKey:`, `addEntriesFromDictionary:`...

```
NSMutableDictionary* mainDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:otherDictionary];
            dictionaries = [mainDictionary objectForKey:@"Dictionaries"];
            [dictionaries addEntriesFromDictionary:otherDictionary];
```

I must be doing something wrong, or not using the function correct. An example of how to append my dictionary with `Three`, `Four`, etc. would be very helpful. thanks.

Comment: Where did the `otherDictionary` come from? By any chance, did it come from some serialized form?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Yes, it is serialized using `[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:kNilOptions format:NULL error:NULL];` and it's loaded by the user from another .plist file.

Comment: ...and then it is deserialized, right? Do you get the "Invalid selector `addEntriesFromDictionary:` is sent to..." crash on the third line of your code snippet?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I've prpbably had every error in the book trying to get this to work. I've had the invalid selector many times at some point on this. I also seem to get data is nil quite a bit too. But yes, invalid selector is one of the primary issues. It doesn't have any errors as of this very moment, although it erases all the other dictionaries when I add a new one for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make this call

```
NSMutableDictionary* mainDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:otherDictionary];
```

the only mutable dictionary that you are guaranteed to get is the outer one (i.e. the `mainDictionary`). If objects inside `otherDictionary` are mutable, they would remain mutable; if the objects inside `otherDictionary` are immutable, they would remain immutable.

It appears that the `otherDictionary` that you are passing to `initWithDictionary:` has been constructed from a property list. If this is the case, you can force all its containers to be mutable by passing `NSPropertyListMutableContainers` to the `propertyListWithData:options:format:error:` method, like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *otherDictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization
    propertyListWithData:myData
                 options:NSPropertyListMutableContainers
                  format:NULL
                   error:NULL
];
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll try this right now and let you know the result, thank you!

Comment: Hi dasblinkenlight - i tried your updated code and had the same tyoe of scenario. [I posted my entire code in a gist here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a7915ba7d3a1a6b07ef0), so if you have time take a quick look. The two plist are read from the desktop. Thanks very much :)

Comment: @ctfd It looks like you need to reverse the order of calls to `readDictOne` and `readOtherDict`, because `readOtherDict` needs to go first. Otherwise, `readDictOne` will see a `nil` in `nextDict`. You also need to remove the local declaration of `nextDict` inside the `readOtherDict` method, because it "shadows" the global dictionary used in `readDictOne`.

Comment: I switched the calls (which I had noticed were backwards too), and removed the local declaration of the `nextDict` and it helped. I'm not sure if it's just me or not, but NSDictionary is very cumbersome it seems. Anyway, thanks for your help :)